# Per version (1.0,1.1,2.0,3.0,3.5), how many classes are in the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, statistics

Per version (1.0, 1.1, 2.0, 3.0, 3.5), how many classes are in the .NET framework?

I am looking for the information for a presentation that I'm going to give for a class in my Master's program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See Brad Abrams's blog post *[Number of Types in the .NET Framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2008/03/17/number-of-types-in-the-net-framework.aspx)*.

Answer (score 0):

Dont answer with like , if the link down people will not find the answer 
I copy the answer from blog

Occasionally I get asked how big the .NET Framework is in terms of surface area for developers.  As you might guess this is something we track.  As you can see, in each release we are adding new functionality that make it easier to build .NET applications.    The number of types in the .NET Framework is 11,417!  Any guesses on how many types will be in .NET Framework 4.0?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]