# Good naming for domain services layer

Tags: c#, architecture, naming, domainservices

### Abstract

Which name is better?

- `Domain.PersonService`
- `DomainServices.PersonService`
- `DomainServices.PersonDomainService` (consider some longer names like `PersonDomainServiceModelDecorator`)

or something else?

### Situation

We have a framework in which there are some base classes for each layer. Ex. Repository, Domain Services, UI, etc.

Each logical layer has a name which is used as its namespace:

- "Data" for data layer that contains repositories; Ex. `Fx.Data.DbContextRepository`
- "Services" for domain (not web) service layer; Ex. `Fx.Services.CrudService`
- "Web.UI" for Web UI layer; Ex. `Fx.Web.UI.Controllers.CrudController`

We also follow the same rule for end-projects whith some extra layers:

- "Data" Ex. `Project.Data.PersonRepository`
- "Services" Ex. `Project.Services.PersonService`
- "Web.UI" Ex. `Project.Web.UI.Controllers.PersonController`
- "Entities" for code-first entities; Ex. `Entities.Person`
- "Models" for object models; Ex. Models.Person.Criteria, `Models.Person.PersonDeleteModel`

My focus is on "Domain Service" layer but any ideas about other layers are also welcomed.

We've finally come to the conclusion that "Services" is not a suitable name for "Domain Services" as it may cause ambiguity between a "Web Service" or "Domain Service" layer.

Now we are changing the "Services" namespace to "Domain" or "DomainServices". But we have another problem. We put a "Service" suffix for every domain service class (Ex. `PersonService`). Now it seems ugly to have "DomainService" suffix (Ex. `DomainServices.PersonDomainServer` or `DomainServices.DomainPersonService`).

So it can be prettier to use "Domain" as namespace while class names show that they're services under domain namespace (Ex. `Domain.PersonService`).

Answer (score 6):

I would go for two simple ideas:

1. try to define full names (namespace + type name) without
   redundancy (the same name portion - Domain, Person, Service, Model,
   Controller, ... - should not appear twice) whenever possible
2. get inspiration from the .NET framework itself. There are [more than 40000 classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406996/number-of-classes-in-net) in there! Open all the
   assemblies in a tool such as .NET Reflector or ILSpy and study
   it carefully.

I would come up with something like this:

```
Domain
 + Person
 + PersonService // Domain service
Domain.Data
 + PersonRepository
Domain.ServiceModel // WCF, etc. I chose the same namespace as .NET Framework
 + PersonService // Service implementation, this is really a service so "service" redundancy seems unavoidable here
Domain.Web.UI
 + PersonController
```

Ok, it has the obvious inconvenient that the same type name appears multiple times in the hierarchy. Well, but that's why namespaces (and namespace aliases) exists also. I think it's not such a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see any difference between `Domain` and `DomainServices` in your project? If you want to keep services and other domain entities in separate namespaces I believe you will need to move `PersonService` to `DomainServices` namespace.

Most of the time we do not look into namespace, we only mention classes that's why I think it is fine to have `DomainServices` namespace. At the same point of time if you have single domain across the application and do not have plan to separate it, I think it will be better to call it `Domain.PersonService`

Regarding the word 'Doman' in the class names, I really don't like this because it adds complexity to the name. You should try to build your application that way to be sure if you are opening `PersonService` you should be 100% sure it is domain service. You know that when you are opening `PersonRepository`, it is `Data` layer, the same for domain.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in either of these two ways:

1) Why not have subnamespaces for `Services`:

- `Services.Web` for web servies
- `Services.Domain` for domain servces

On another note, I would remove `Web` from `Web.UI` (provided that you do only have a web based UI).

2) If web services are actually living in the web layer they could be in `Web.Services` namespace in that case `Web.UI` is also acceptable. Domain Services would live simply in `Services` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to put it as
**`<Company>.<Component>.<SubComponent>.<Module>.DLL**`. 
Microsoft recommends something similiar on this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229048(v=vs.100).aspx and an example will be **Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Dll**

Hence, you might want to go with `Company.Domain.PersonService`